# Can't call table columns in mysql to my vb.net application for a search bar

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need help with my search bar for a database in a datagridview in vb.net. I don't know if I'm stupid or not but I can't seem to call my table columns in my phpmyadmin. Any fixes? I've been searching for one. > I'm a Noob sorry.

```
Private Sub SearchTxt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchTxt.TextChanged
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=agents"
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("FULLNAME Like '%" & SearchTxt.Text & "&'")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End Sub
```

whenever I try to type in the searchbox I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find column [FULLNAME].
>
> Blockquote

Comment: It is a new dataview on a new Datatable, so of course with no data and no columns it wont know what FullName refers to.

Comment: soo, what do I put? (I can't understand why I'm a full blown retard)

Comment: nvm got it sorry!!

Comment: Also `.NET` should be able to able to do prepared statements i advice you using them... Also are you sure you want to expose your MySQL username/password in a client app which can be decompiled

Comment: I'm just doing this for a project in school haha! I'll learn someday

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how stupid I am finding this out by myself.

```
Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
Private Sub SearchTxt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchTxt.TextChanged
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("FULLNAME Like '%" & SearchTxt.Text & "%'")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End Sub
```

> I turned dbDataSet into a new global variable. (because I have a load system that needs the DataTable.)
>
> I have an & for an % in line 6
>
> and I removed the connection lmao

Comment: it's a bad answer I know